# what is the resolution setting mean in adobe photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, canvas

if I already have a height and width of 1920 1080 then what is the setting that says Resolution "72" used for? I have not used adobe-photoshop in forever and I am just getting back into it. so sorry if this has been asked before. see picture below to explain what I am trying to ask.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells how to convert your artwork to physical units.  So essentially its how many pixels form an inch. If you design for print you should set it to 150-300 and type physical dimensions of your output (not pixels). If not leave it as 72.

For historical reasons 72 means value not set, which in turn means designed for a screen device. (Why 72? Adobes internal unit is a postscript point so 72 pixels per inch means one internal unit equals to one pixel which is nice if the unit is meaningless for you)

Comment: thank you for trying to explain this too my cave-man mindset of a brain :D